# Can't create a swapfile for Solaris 11.3

Tags: solaris, swap, virtual-memory

My compiles are failing on Solaris 11.3 due to out of memory kills. The box is an UltraSPARC workstation with 600GB drives and 8 GB of RAM and a fresh OS install. It is absolutely befuddling there's not enough memory for the system and I am suffering DoS'es out of the box.

I'm trying to follow [Adding Swap Space on a Solaris System](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24457_01/html/E21988/gipoj.html) to add some more space.

```
# Step 1
$ sudo su -
...

# Step 2
# mkdir /var
mkdir: Failed to make directory "/var"; File exists
# mkfile 2048m /var/swap

# Step 3
# ls -l /var/swap
-rw-------   1 root     root     2147483648 Jul 16 11:42 /var/swap

# Step 4
# swap -a /var/swap
"/var/swap" is not valid for swapping.
It must be a block device or a regular file with the
"save user text on execution" bit set.
```

I have two questions. First, what is so broken at Oracle that nearly every document is wrong?

Second, how do I create the god damn swap space? How do I make the ***T*** appear in an `ls` listing?

---

Here is the doc's Step 3. Notice the addition of the ***T***:

> Verify that the file was created by typing:
>
> ```
> ls -l /directory/swap-file-name
> ```
>
> The new file appears in the directory. For example:
>
> ```
> ls -l /foo/16mswap    -rw------T   1 root     other    16777216 Dec 12 14:24 /foo/16mswap
> ```

Comment: *It is absolutely befuddling there's not enough memory for the system* What's the initial swap configuration? Solaris doesn't lie about how much memory is available - no memory overcommit is done, so if you don't have enough swap, that's what you get. *what is so broken at Oracle that nearly every document is wrong?*  The document you posted excerpts from is not wrong.  It's an example that happens to be incomplete.  The [Solaris 11 `swap` man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29031/swap-1m.html) even states: "Using a regular file for swap is not supported on a ZFS file system."

Answer (score 4):

The page you found relates to Solaris Studio 12.3, which dates back to 2011, and a time when Solaris still used swap files.  With Solaris 11.3, which uses ZFS as the root filesystem, the process is slightly different, as a real block device is required.  Fortunately, ZFS makes using real block devices very easy, via ZFS Volumes.

First, check for your existing volumes:

```
zfs list -t volume
```

You will most likely see a volume named `swap` @ `/rpool/swap`, so you'll need a different name for your new device, like `swap2`.

Here's what I see:

```
bash-[501]# zfs list -t volume
NAME         USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
rpool/dump  3.08G   139G  2.99G  -
rpool/swap  2.06G   139G  2.00G  -
```

Also, take a look at your existing swap devices:

```
bash-[502]# swap -l
swapfile             dev    swaplo   blocks     free
/dev/zvol/dsk/rpool/swap 275,1         8  4194296  4194296
```

Next step is to create the new volume.  In the next command, the `-V` option indicates that we are creating a raw block device, as opposed to a device with a filesystem, and the `2G` is the size:

```
bash-[503]# zfs create -V 2G rpool/swap2
```

Now you'll see your list of volumes has changed:

```
bash-[504]# zfs list -t volume
NAME          USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
rpool/dump   3.08G   137G  2.99G  -
rpool/swap   2.06G   137G  2.00G  -
rpool/swap2  2.06G   137G  2.00G  -
```

Then you can activate that block device as swap:

```
bash-[505]# swap -a /dev/zvol/dsk/rpool/swap2
```

And, as always, you can see your swap devices with `swap -l`.

```
bash-[506]# swap -l
swapfile             dev    swaplo   blocks     free
/dev/zvol/dsk/rpool/swap 275,1         8  4194296  4194296
/dev/zvol/dsk/rpool/swap2 275,3         8  4194296  4194296
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim. [`zfs set volsize=2G rpool/swap`](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-admin/monitor-swap-solaris-zfs-2216650.html) was sufficient to compile a program. I'm still amazed the compiler does not work out of the box and something special has to be done...

Answer (score 2):

The `T` attribute may be set on the file using

```
chmod +t filename
```

Note that using a swap file is not supported if the file lives on an ZFS filesystem.